# How to Pass every Php value to javascript URL (only showing 1 same row record)

Tags: javascript, php, html, parameter-passing

Need help on below coding.
However I got few running no, when I press edit button it only show running no '1', other running no like 2 or 3 also showing running no 1 when i press edit on the row 2 and row 3. 
I got a problem in `index.php` file:

```
    <html>  

    <?php


                    $rb = $connect->Execute("SELECT * FROM IT_Dept.dbo.testingHeader A LEFT JOIN IT_Dept.dbo.testingDetail B 
                    ON A.invoiceno=B.invoiceno_dt
                    WHERE A.invoiceno = '".$search."'");



        }

                                     $invoiceno = $rb->Fields("invoiceno");
                                     $company = $rb->Fields("company");
                                     $custname = $rb->Fields("custname");




                                    $newadd=str_replace("<br />","\n",$custadd);
                                    //table details


                                    ?>


      <body>

    <?php 

    echo "<form id= 'form2' method='post'><table id='tabledesc' border=1>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Description </th>
                                <th>Qty</th>
                                <th >Unit Price(Before GST)</th>
                                <th>Total(Before GST)</th>
                                <th  >*Total GST</th>
                                <th  >Amount(RM)</th> 
                                <th  >Tax input/output</th>
                                <th  >Debit Acc</th>

                                </tr>";

    while(!$rb->EOF) {

     $description = $rb->Fields("description");
                                      $invoiceno_dt = $rb->Fields("invoiceno_dt");
                                      $runningno = $rb->Fields("runningno");
                                      $qty = $rb->Fields("qty");
                                       $unitprice = $rb->Fields("unitprice");
                                         $totalb4gst = $rb->Fields("totalb4gst");
                                         $gst = $rb->Fields("gst");
                                          $amount = $rb->Fields("amount");
                                         >Fields("creditacc");



                                      $description = $description->value;
                                    $invoiceno_dt = $invoiceno_dt->value;
                                    $runningno = $runningno->value;
                                    $qty = $qty->value;
                                    $unitprice = $unitprice->value;
                                    $totalb4gst = $totalb4gst->value;
                                    $gst = $gst->value;
                                    $amount = $amount->value;                               

    echo "<tr><td>".$description."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$qty."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$unitprice."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$totalb4gst."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$gst."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$amount."</td>";


    echo "<input type='hidden' name = 'runningno' id='runningno' value = ' $runningno ' >";

    echo "<td><button onclick='openedit()'>Edit</button></td>";
invoiceno_dt=".$invoiceno_dt."&runningno=".$runningno."'>Edit</a></td>";
invoiceno_dt=".$invoiceno_dt."&runningno=".$runningno."'>x</a></td><tr>";

    echo "<td><button onclick='opendelete()'>Delete</button></td>";

    $rb->MoveNext();

    }

    ?>

            </table></form></body>   

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var popup;


         function openedit() {


             var myinvoice = document.getElementById("invoiceno").value;

              var no = <?php echo $runningno; ?>;
            alert(no);

            popup = window.open("edit.php?invoiceno="+myinvoice+'&runningno='+no, "Popup", "width=500,height=600");
            popup.focus();
        }


            popup.focus();
        }


    </script>
    <?php

    $rb->close;

    $connect->close;


    ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `echo`s be contained in `<?php ?>` blocks?

Comment: Hi, ya it is with php block. here are only some portion of my code.

Comment: I don't understand at all what are you saying

Comment: and please note that id <--- must be unique. You must not have same id

Comment: runningno should be $runningno in second echo

Comment: hi, i mean i have a invoiceno which contain in both header(primary key) and detail(primary key) table, inside detail table i have few record with same invoice no and different running no. now i need to pass the running no into javascript url. but when i press the edit button it show me the only running no 1.

Comment: `openedit(\''+runningno+'\')` looks a bit odd. Is the parameter supposed to be a string or the value of the PHP variable?

Comment: i have uploaded a full version of my index.php. plz have a look ya.

Comment: Hi @apokryfos, the runningno shud be the php variable $runningno. do you have any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the running number to the page for example by doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var no = <?php echo $runningNo; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: The OP has indicated that they have multiple buttons which should each have a different running number. A global variable is definitely not the solution.

Comment: Hi , after i change the code it can pass the value, but same running no for record 1 and record 2. do i need to create loop for it? so it can loop all the data inside database?

Comment: hi @Quentin, do u know how to pass different running no?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
echo "<td><button onclick=\"openedit('{$runningno}')\">Edit</button></td>";
```

Apart from that, you better to remove the spaces in value attribute in input field.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='runningno' id='runningno' value ='$runningno' />";
```

Comment: Hi, it can pass the value edy. but cant loop thru all the data inside database. it can only loop the 1st one. eg: i have different record with different runningno. but when i click button on second record it running no also show one only.

Answer (score 0):

Use  as suggested for template files

```
<html>
<!-- HTML code is here -->    
<input type='hidden' name = 'runningno' id='runningno' value = '<?php print $runningno; ?>'></input>
<!-- Some other html -->
<?php

//your php code here
?>
<!-- HTML again -->
</html>
```

Same for js inside html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var testJsValue = "<?php print $ValueFromPHP; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, i have uploaded a full version of code. when i press record 1 and record 2 it also show runningno 2. Do i need to create a array or loop for it? so it can loop thru all row of my data.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo '<td><button onclick="openedit(\''.$runningno.'\')">Edit</button></td>';
```

I think this code will be work properly.

Comment: Hi, it can pass in only the same row value. eg: the runningno always show value ="1", but inside database i have value 2,3 also

Comment: You can add javascript auto increment value. 

I add this for you 

`var value;var no = yourcomeingrequestvalue;var value = parseInt(no 10);value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;value++; example hr.send("rdid="+value)`; then you can send value